# If $f(x)^2=x+(x+1)f(x+2)$, what is $f(1)$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations, nested-radicals

Suppose $f$: $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)^2 = x + (x+1)f(x+2)$, what is $f(1)$? Or more in general, what is $f(x)$?

The motivation behind this problem is that I want to find what the number of this nested radical $\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{3+4\sqrt{5+6\sqrt{7+8...}}}}$. This can be written more generally as $f(x)=\sqrt{x+(x+1)f(x+2)}$ where $x=1$. This is where the problem arises from. If anybody can find an expression for the nested radical or find $f(x)$ I would be very happy!

Comment: [Ramanujan's nested radical](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Ramanujan's_infinite_radicals) is very similar to this, and has a simple, linear solution. Maybe you could try $f(x)=ax+b$ first, and see whether it works.

Comment: Since $f(-1)^2=-1$, the function is not real-valued, or at least is not defined everywhere.  Did you mean positive reals only?

Comment: Ramanujan's nested radical is actually where I got the idea of the problem from! I tried his technique, but it didn't work. The solution also seems to converge to 3.598544540688569 which the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced) is not able to find an expression for, so there might not be a closed form expression for $f(x)$ or $f(1)$.

Comment: Yes, positive reals! My bad!

Answer (score 6):

Rewrite the equation to get $f(x+2)=(f(x)^2-x)/(x+1)$. Thus you may define $f$ arbitrarily in the interval $[0,2)$ and extend it to $[0,4)$ by using the equation. And so on. Choosing $f$ continuous on $[0,2)$ such that $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=f(0)^2$ gives (all) continuous solution. Thus the value of $f(1)$ plays no particular role.

Comment: Then the simplest solution is $f(x)=0$ on $[0,\infty)$. If the nested radical indeed converges to the vicinity of $3.598544540688569$ then the formulation of $f(x)$ evidently does not capture the essence of the nested radical. Curious.

Comment: That's **not correct** : the derivatives are also subject to bounds: see my answer.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: the "curiosity" is actually due to that also the derivatives of $f(x)$ are related : see my answer.

Comment: @GCab Yes, agreed.

Answer (score 4):

The functional equation for $f(x)$ actually implies functional
relations also for all its derivatives
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  f(x)^{\,2}  = x + \left( {x + 1} \right)f(x + 2) \hfill \cr 
  2f(x)f'(x) = 1 + f(x + 2) + \left( {x + 1} \right)f'(x + 2) \hfill \cr 
  2f'(x)^{\,2}  + 2f(x)f''(x) = 2f'(x + 2) + \left( {x + 1} \right)f''(x + 2) \hfill \cr 
  \quad \quad  \vdots  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
so that
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  f(2) = f(0)^{\,2}  \hfill \\
  f'(2) = 2f(0)f'(0) - f(0)^{\,2}  - 1 \hfill \\
  f''(2) = 2f'(0)^{\,2}  + 2f(0)f''(0) - 4f(0)f'(0) + 2f(0)^{\,2}  + 2 \hfill \\
  \quad \quad  \vdots  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$

Therefore, being $f(x)$ continuous, we are not free to fix $f(x)\quad |\;0\le x < 2$
equal to whatever continuous function respecting only $f(2)=f(0)^2$.
Instead it shall be such as to respect the functional relation, at $x$ and $x+2$, for all the derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggested alternate approach.

Consider the recursive sequence $a_k\in\mathbb{R}$

\begin{eqnarray}
a_0&=&\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{3+4\sqrt{5+6\sqrt{7+8\sqrt{9+...}}}}}\\
a_{k+1}&=&\frac{a_k^2+1}{2(k+1)}-1 \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

This gives the increasing unbounded sequence

\begin{eqnarray}
a_1&=&\sqrt{3+4\sqrt{5+6\sqrt{7+8\sqrt{9+10\sqrt{11+...}}}}}\\
a_2&=&\sqrt{5+6\sqrt{7+8\sqrt{9+10\sqrt{11+12\sqrt{13+...}}}}}\\
a_3&=&\sqrt{7+8\sqrt{9+10\sqrt{11+12\sqrt{13+14\sqrt{15+...}}}}}\\
&\vdots&
\end{eqnarray}

This converts the problem of finding $a_0$ into the problem of finding a generating function

\begin{equation}
G(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots
\end{equation}

and a formula for the general term $a_n$ of the coefficient sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the function exists and converges as its argument tends to infinity.
In particular, there is some real $x_0 > 0$ and $d > 0$ such that $0 \le f(x) \le d$ for all $x \ge x_0$.
There must then also exist some $x_1 \ge x_0$ such that $x_1 > d^2$.

It follows that for any $x \ge x_1$, we have
$f(x+2) = (f(x)^2-x)/(x+1) \le (d^2 - x)/(x+1) < 0$, a contradiction.

So the function does not converge.

Comment: ".. does not converge": you mean for $x \to \infty$ ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out the ambiguity.